AWS Lambda/S3 Bucket to Supabase
I have a parquet file created in an AWS lambda function. The lambda function takes an xlsx file and reformats/fixes/edit column headings, etc it, and produces a parquet file, sending it to an AMS S3 bucket - the rows in the file are ready to be upserted into a table in Supabase that has the same column headings.
The lambda function takes roughly 10-20 seconds to execute. With this in mind...
1 - Is it possible to send the parquet file directly to a foreign table in Supabase as part of the lambda function? Or...
2 - Is it possible to upsert the rows from the parquet file directly into 'proper' table in Supabase? Or...
3 - Can Supabase be notified when the lambda function has finished executing (or the resulting parquet file has appeared in the bucket on AWS), and then use the Supabase AWS S3 to automatically read the parquet contents into a foreign table
Help greatly appreciated.
